# Elements overlap when wrapping to next line

Tags: html, css

How can I prevent these buttons from overlapping each other when they wrap to the next line?

```css
.button-link {
  background: #4479BA;
  border: solid 1px #20538D;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #FFF;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://citieasydeals.com/index.jsp">Amazon</a>
<a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://citieasydeals.com/index.jsp">Auction</a>
<a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://citieasydeals.com/index.jsp">LinkedIn</a>
<a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="#">Mediacom</a>
<a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="http://mediacomtoday.com/usagemeter/index.php">Mediacom Usuage</a>
<a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a>
<a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://citieasydeals.com/index.jsp">Twitter</a>
<a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://www.bankofamerica.com//">BofA</a>
<a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://www.bankofamerica.com//">Wells Fargo</a>
<a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://www.bankofamerica.com//">Chase</a>
<a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://www.bankofamerica.com//">Citi</a>
<a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://citieasydeals.com/index.jsp">Mint</a>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fcrypo80/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fcrypo80/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buttons overlap because they are ["inline"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) elements. Vertical padding on inline elements has no effect on surrounding elements. See [this article on maxdesign.com](http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/) for more information.

One method of preventing the overlap is to set each button to `display:inline-block`.
I also recommend adding bottom margin to create some space between "rows".

> Inline-Block: The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much like a replaced element would)
>   - [display @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Keep in mind that white space between `inline-block` elements will be respected (displayed). If the extra space affects your design, you may want to remove it. One method is to remove space between the elements in your code. In my demonstration, I have moved each closing `</a>` to the next line, just before the next opening `<a>`, so that there's no space between one element and the next.

```css
.button-link {
  background: #4479BA;
  border: solid 1px #20538D;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #FFF;
  margin:0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://citieasydeals.com/index.jsp">Amazon
</a><a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://citieasydeals.com/index.jsp">Auction
</a><a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://citieasydeals.com/index.jsp">LinkedIn
</a><a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="#">Mediacom
</a><a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="http://mediacomtoday.com/usagemeter/index.php">Mediacom Usuage
</a><a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow
</a><a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://citieasydeals.com/index.jsp">Twitter
</a><a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://www.bankofamerica.com//">BofA
</a><a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://www.bankofamerica.com//">Wells Fargo
</a><a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://www.bankofamerica.com//">Chase
</a><a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://www.bankofamerica.com//">Citi
</a><a target="_blank" class="button-link" href="https://citieasydeals.com/index.jsp">Mint</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `float:left;` and `margin-top:2px;` to class `.button-link`

```
.button-link {
    background: #4479ba none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #20538d;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    float:left;
    margin-top:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` and some `margin-top/margin-bottom`.

```
.button-link {
    margin-top: 5px;
    background: #4479BA;
    border: solid 1px #20538D;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #FFF;
    margin-right: 10px;
    moz-border-radius: 4px;
    moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    moz-user-select: none;
    ms-user-select: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    user-select: none;
    webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    webkit-user-select: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0j19yt0v/)